# How to place the text above the table when exporting excel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel, angularjs

I exported an excel file and I want that this text is in above the table. How to do that?
Here is the angular js code:

```
$scope.generateLedger = (supplier_id) => {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '../reportsController/ledgerController/getLedger/' + supplier_id
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (response.data) {
                $scope.ledger = response.data;
                $scope.tableShow = true;
                $scope.sup_name = $scope.getSupName(supplier_id);

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#supplierLedgerTable').DataTable({
                        dom: `<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'pB>>`,
                        "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
                        buttons: [
                            {
                                extend: 'excel',
                                text: 'Export to Excel',
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
                                },
                                title: 'Supplier Ledger - ' + $scope.sup_name
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
            } else {
                $scope.tableShow = false;
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'No Data Found.'
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

Here is the generated excel with table and I manually place the text above it because Its not working when I place it in the angular js code:
[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn7Ga.jpg)

I want someone here to fix the code my code. Can you help me!

Comment: How is this related to php?

Comment: Im using Codeigniter 3 with angular js

Comment: No i meant in regards to your question and issue you are facing, how is php related to this?

Comment: Im sorry, the tagging of php is not right in this section because its a script but I already fixed the issue by using excel.js library